# window is not defined webpack 3 : ReactJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I'm using webpack 3 for my reactJs App.When i run my app,i'm getting `window is not defined` error like below.[image]

Comment: Where are using `window` in your code? please post the code as well in the question.

Comment: i'm using `windows` in several places in my code well as index.html.i have commented all that is with `windows` and tried to build.but still got that error.

Comment: Yes, so somewhere the `window` variable is not declared or `require`ed. This is not webpacks poblem, it's saying the code has problems

Comment: Is there is a way to detect and handle this from one end.i mean from 'webpack.js' or index.js ?

Comment: There won't be, as the code has errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when using eslint. By adding this config I manage to fix it

in .eslintrc file

```
"globals": {
    "Promise": true,
    "alert": true,
    "global": true, // here
    "window": true,
    "document": true,
    "process": true,
    "module": true,
    "console": true,
    "sessionStorage": true,
    "localStorage": true
  }
```